# How to mount Ubuntu partition permanently writeable?

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, fstab

When I boot I always get the login terminal (not the gui). I always have to use the recovery mode and remount the Ubuntu partition with:

```
$ mount -o rw,remount /
```

After that, I get into the normal login gui. This is my `fstab` content:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/f573b350-2491-47d4-93cf-3d403cbbe3e0 /mnt/f573b350-2491-47d4-93cf-3d403cbbe3e0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/59A2385E617A5117 /mnt/59A2385E617A5117 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/5df08936-a7c1-4836-aef8-d8e6591da647 /mnt/5df08936-a7c1-4836-aef8-d8e6591da647 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

How can I auto mount / and make it permanently writeable? Everytime I restart Ubuntu I have to redo the steps.

Comment: why do you log into console instead of gui when you first start? what errors are you showing in the console when it comes up or do you just not have it set to boot to a gui and log in and type startx ... I don't understand the problem fully ... .. when logging into the recovery console it is always read only and you always have to run the remount command .. that is just how it is in recovery mode. I think first you need to find out why you need to go into recovery mode. Try starting normally and if it goes to terminal just log in and type `startx` and see if the GUI launches.

Comment: I have no choice when I boot. When I enter my login credentials (at boot) Ubuntu opens the terminal (without the gui). I can't go father than that.

Comment: Your fstab also look very odd for a standard install .. I have never seen any using the /dev/disk/by-uuid/ and /mnt/uuid... usually they are like this `UUID=0ae6d08b-d9c5-4109-9100-9a18fb068b2e / ext4 defaults 0 1`  That was my root partition and my swap partition looks like this `UUID=c5653896-3d1b-48b4-855a-e76e6d88711a swap swap sw 0 0` You may have something special set up there that I am not familiar with but I guess this could also be causing your issues if its not set right

Comment: when it go to terminal .. .can you log in and type startx

Comment: also in terminal can you run `sudo blkid` and is add it to the question so we can see how your drive is set up .. I may be able to set you up with a fstab that is more like mine that may work for you

Comment: if you are having issues because it only prints it out in terminal and you have no way of copying it to paste it in here .. it seems you can access the files to copy .. you can run `sudo blkid > /tmp/blkid.txt` and that should save the output to a file called blkid.txt in the tmp folder.

Comment: What about creating a script that does it? Then you could just type `boot` at the prompt. (Assuming you called the script boot.sh)

Comment: he has more issues if he has to force read/write on root every time he boots ... I have a feeling that his fstab is not proper .. he is mounting all drives on /mnt/uuid  not sure this is correct .. he doesn't seem to have a mount point for  root or swap .. unless somehow the /mnt/uuid is pointing to them in some manner

Comment: Okay, I fixed it with both of your help: First, I fixed the error from startx and then I updated my fstab. Thank you!

Comment: glad we could help .. you can give us a little rep by clicking the little ^  next to the comments that helped :D